# I keep on getting the error: cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.command = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.command.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Primio Has Activated :)');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'flip') {
        client.command.get('flip').execute(message, args,);

    } else if (command === 'help') {
      client.command.get('help').execute(message, args,);
}
});


client.login('token');
```

I keep getting errors that say:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pokey\Desktop\Primio\main.js:29:35)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Pokey\Desktop\Primio\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Pokey\Desktop\Primio\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Pokey\Desktop\Primio\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Pokey\Desktop\Primio\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Pokey\Desktop\Primio\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Pokey\Desktop\Primio\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Pokey\Desktop\Primio\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:833:20)
```

Comment: It looks like `client.command.get('flip')` returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you use command handler like this you need to show us the **flip.js**. At start the flip.js needs to be in folder names **commands** then in file you need to add this code:  `module.exports ={ name:'flip' desciption: 'your comment' execute(message,args,Discord){your code here}}`
Second thing that you made mistake is a **,** in execute
your code should look like this so far `if (command === 'flip') { client.commands.get('flip').execute(message, args, Discord);`
If you still gets error that's can mean your execute(message, args, Discord) is not same as this in **flip.js**. Give me feedback if the problem is solved :D